# delete columns from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out code to generate that loops through the contents of a table and checks if it is a valid column still and delete all of the columns that are not valid anymore.

```
declare @counter int
declare @col_count int
declare @col_name char(100)
declare @temp_sql char(100)
set @counter = 0

SELECT @col_count = COUNT(*) from sys.columns 
where Object_ID = Object_ID(N'test') 
AND name <> 'pk_test'

while @counter < @col_count
begin  
  with CTE as (
    select name, row_number() over (order by column_id) as ColNo
    from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('test') AND name <> 'pk_test'
  )
  select @col_name = name from CTE where ColNo = ((@counter) + 1)

  SET @temp_sql = 'ALTER TABLE test DROP column ' + @col_name + ';'
  EXECUTE (@temp_sql);

  set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

for some reason EXECUTE is causing the code to skip every other call, but if I take out the execute with a comment and throw in a print, it will show all the valid drop statements.

I have tried doing this:

```
SET @temp_sql = @temp_swl + 'ALTER TABLE test DROP column ' + @col_name
enter code here
```

I was attempting to combine all the alter tables at once, but it doesn't seem to work.

I feel I am missing something small!

Comment: Just curious, why not push the valid columns into a new table, then drop the old table and rename the new?

Comment: @brian it may be a lot of data, and there may be many foreign keys pointing at the column being kept.

Comment: frankly, because I didn't think of it :-), also I want to retain data if possible, I have a "reset" flag if the dev wants to completely drop the table, or if they simply want to "update" it.

I am still toying around and finalizing everything. I will keep this in mind though!

Comment: @Krum110487 what is your goal for this? To reclaim space or just clean up the table definition?

Comment: I am working on a library that can be use to re-build a database from a set of classes on each devs machine (much like entity framework), including the ability to update it. Essentially to clean up table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach, that doesn't require a cursor (which is another name for a while loop) and has no potential for skipping anything. Note that I am making the assumption that "not valid" means "does not have the name `pk_test`". If "not valid" means something else, please clarify. Of course you probably want to make sure that the table has a column called `pk_test` first, otherwise the last `ALTER` will fail - your code doesn't currently check for that.

```
DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(512), -- the table we're affecting
        @c SYSNAME;       -- the column we want to keep

SELECT @t = N'dbo.test', @c = N'pk_test';


IF EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@t)
    AND name = @c
)
BEGIN

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'';

  SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
    ALTER TABLE ' + @t + ' DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
  FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@t) AND name <> @c;

  PRINT @sql;
  -- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Sorry, can't delete all columns from ' + @t + '.';
END
```

Comment: I really need to learn T-SQL, this helps immensely, all I need to do now is generate my list of current columns in the table and this will remove all the ones not listed! great!

also, is there an easier way to do a list of items instead of simply AND (name <> 'column 1 OR name <> 'column2' OR name <> 'column3'), this is what I plan on generating, I assume, I could simply generate that for the "c" variable.

Comment: @Krum110487 what version of SQL Server? If 2008+ you could not exists against a table-valued parameter. If earlier you could just populate a #temp table manually and do a not exists against that.

Answer (score 2):

You are regenerating the table with the counter each time -- except you are removing one row (i.e. column) sometimes with the `alter table` statement.

Instead, generate the table first and then loop through it.  So, replace this:

```
while @counter < @col_count
begin  
  with CTE as (
    select name, row_number() over (order by column_id) as ColNo
    from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('test') AND name <> 'pk_test'
  )
  select @col_name = name from CTE where ColNo = ((@counter) + 1)

  SET @temp_sql = 'ALTER TABLE test DROP column ' + @col_name + ';'
  EXECUTE (@temp_sql);

  set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

With this:

```
declare @columns table (colnum int not null identity(1, 1), colname varchar(255));

insert into @columns(colname)
    select name
    from sys.columns
    where object_id = object_id('test') AND name <> 'pk_test';

set @col_count = max(colnum) from @columns;

while @counter < @col_count
begin  

  select @col_name = name from @columns where ColNo = ((@counter) + 1);

  SET @temp_sql = 'ALTER TABLE test DROP column ' + @col_name + ';'
  EXECUTE (@temp_sql);

  set @counter = @counter + 1;
end;
```

I'm not going to comment about what you are doing, but this should fix the "skipping" problem, by precalculating the list of columns.  That way, the list is not affected by the `alter table` statement.

Comment: AH, this makes sense! The point to this code is for database generation, so basically for dev only, not a production script, just something to make my life easier, thanks!